# Xamarin.Forms Page Animation

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to make an animation for my page. I want that animation to get fired only when the page is first loaded.
My animation code is working, sample:

```
public async Task BackgroundFlyUp()
        {
            var destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, Application.Current.MainPage.Height * (1 - FoodViewsConstants.FLY_UP_END),
                Application.Current.MainPage.Width, Application.Current.MainPage.Height * FoodViewsConstants.FLY_UP_END);

            await FlyUp.LayoutTo(destinationRect, FoodViewsConstants.FLY_UP_SPEED, Easing.Linear);
            await ContentGrid.FadeTo(1, FoodViewsConstants.CONTENT_FADE_SPEED);
        }
```

Although I don't want my animation to get fired every time `OnAppearing` is fired, I've tried to add the animation code in my `OnAppearing` method but it doesn't work right. (the fade is working but the `FlyUp` not) and being an `async` method, it can't be placed in the constructor. Can you guys help me out?

Comment: Could you provide more details of `FlyUp.LayoutTo`? What is the package of `FlyUp.LayoutTo`?

Comment: `FlyUp` is the name of my absolute layout. With `LayoutTo` I'm changing its height to match the `destinationRect`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my test, I guess you do not get the correct from destinationRect. The `Application.Current.MainPage.Width` and `Application.Current.MainPage.Height` would get the width and height except on initial load when the MainPage hadn't been presented yet.

You could use the screen size instead.

```
 public async Task BackgroundFlyUp()
    {  
        // Get Metrics
        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo; 

        // Width (in pixels)
        var width = mainDisplayInfo.Width;

        // Height (in pixels)
        var height = mainDisplayInfo.Height;


        var destinationRect = new Rectangle(0, height * (1 - FoodViewsConstants.FLY_UP_END),
            width, height * FoodViewsConstants.FLY_UP_END);


        await FlyUp.LayoutTo(destinationRect, 5000, Easing.Linear);
        
        await ContentGrid.FadeTo(1, FoodViewsConstants.CONTENT_FADE_SPEED);
    }
```